# JInternalFrame is taking delay in loading?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jinternalframe

I've created an application in java swing, in which an `JInternalFrame` is visible on clicking a button on `JFrame`. The internalFrame consists of table with 32 columns in which values are added dynamically.

The problem is that when we click on to the button The `JInternalFrame` is taking a bit delay in loading .Is that looping in the code makes it delay

Can anyone please tell me some solution to prevent the delay in loading...

```
public class AttendanceView extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {
    private int count=0;
    String []columnNames={"<html><b>Name</b></html>","<html><b>1</b></html>","<html><b>2</b></html>",""
            + "<html><b>3</b></html>",""+ "<html><b>4</b></html>",""
            + "<html><b>5</b></html>",""+ "<html><b>6</b></html>",""
            + "<html><b>7</b></html>",""+ "<html><b>8</b></html>",""
            + "<html><b>9</b></html>",""+ "<html><b>10</b></html>",""
            + "<html><b>11</b></html>",""+ "<html><b>12</b></html>",""
            + "<html><b>13</b></html>",""+ "<html><b>14</b></html>",""
            + "<html><b>15</b></html>",""+ "<html><b>16</b></html>",""
            + "<html><b>17</b></html>",""+ "<html><b>18</b></html>",""
            + "<html><b>19</b></html>",""+ "<html><b>20</b></html>",""
            + "<html><b>21</b></html>",""+ "<html><b>22</b></html>",""
            + "<html><b>23</b></html>",""+ "<html><b>24</b></html>",""
            + "<html><b>25</b></html>",""+ "<html><b>26</b></html>",""
            + "<html><b>27</b></html>",""+ "<html><b>28</b></html>",""
            + "<html><b>29</b></html>",""+ "<html><b>30</b></html>",""
            + "<html><b>31</b></html>"};
    String dataValues[][];
    public AttendanceView() {
        initComponents();
        try
        {
         dataValues=new String[10][32];
         int i=0;
         for(i=0;i<5;i++)
         {
             for(int j=0;j<32;j++)
             {
                 if(j==0)
               dataValues[i][0]="Manu Suseelan";
                 else
                dataValues[i][j]="<html><body style='background:green;color:green'>&nbsp;&nbsp;|||&nbsp;&nbsp;</center></html>";
             }

         }
         } catch (Exception ex) {System.out.println("sql error:"+ex);
        }


        DefaultTableModel df = new DefaultTableModel();

        df.setDataVector(dataValues,columnNames);
        table.setModel(df);
        int index=0;
        while (index < 32) {
                    TableColumn a = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                    a.setPreferredWidth(100);
                    a.setResizable(false);
                    index++;
                }



        TableColumn a = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        a.setPreferredWidth(1000);

    }
```

...

Comment: Between the loops and the rendering of all the html

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Adapted from *"Between the Devil and the deep blue sea"*?  *"Between the rock and the hard place"*? *"Between the frying pan and the fire"*?.. ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson...... Sir i'm using JTable in JInternalFrame

Comment: I now notice the code is using a `DefaultTableModel` and table.  In that case, see [How to Use Tables: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for how to 'style' the output.  Either that or implement it in a PLAF that will change all tables that use it.  - This is in preference to showing HTML (I'm normally a big advocate).  As alluded to by @MadProgrammer the rendering of the HTML documents (of which there seem to be at least 124) is most likely causing the delay.

Comment: sir is there any problem in using DefaultTableModel

Comment: No problem with using a `DefaultTableModel`, but ***also*** use a `DefaultTableCellRenderer` (as mentioned at the link) ***instead of*** styling the cells with HTML.

Comment: this code can't be caused any delay, your problem(s) is(are) somewhere elsewhere

Comment: sir may be HTML documents causes it delay

Comment: not never, code removed from your try - catch blok

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there no problem with performance, only picture can caused that, put image to the java package, code example (based on last related post @Andrew Thompson), as mentioned, to use Renderer instead of Html formatting,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class TableWithHtml {

    private int count = 0;
    private String[] columnNames = {"<html><b>Name</b></html>", "<html><b>1</b></html>", "<html><b>2</b></html>", ""
        + "<html><b>3</b></html>", "" + "<html><b>4</b></html>", ""
        + "<html><b>5</b></html>", "" + "<html><b>6</b></html>", ""
        + "<html><b>7</b></html>", "" + "<html><b>8</b></html>", ""
        + "<html><b>9</b></html>", "" + "<html><b>10</b></html>", ""
        + "<html><b>11</b></html>", "" + "<html><b>12</b></html>", ""
        + "<html><b>13</b></html>", "" + "<html><b>14</b></html>", ""
        + "<html><b>15</b></html>", "" + "<html><b>16</b></html>", ""
        + "<html><b>17</b></html>", "" + "<html><b>18</b></html>", ""
        + "<html><b>19</b></html>", "" + "<html><b>20</b></html>", ""
        + "<html><b>21</b></html>", "" + "<html><b>22</b></html>", ""
        + "<html><b>23</b></html>", "" + "<html><b>24</b></html>", ""
        + "<html><b>25</b></html>", "" + "<html><b>26</b></html>", ""
        + "<html><b>27</b></html>", "" + "<html><b>28</b></html>", ""
        + "<html><b>29</b></html>", "" + "<html><b>30</b></html>", ""
        + "<html><b>31</b></html>"};
    private String dataValues[][];

    public TableWithHtml() {
        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(2, 3, 2, 3));
        JDesktopPane dtp = new JDesktopPane();
        gui.add(dtp);
        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Component c = (Component) e.getSource();
                JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(c, "Message");
            }
        };
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 13; ii++) {
            try {
                dataValues = new String[10][32];
                int i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
                        if (j == 0) {
                            dataValues[i][0] = "Manu Suseelan";
                        } else {
                            dataValues[i][j] = "<html><body style='background:green;color:green'>&nbsp;&nbsp;|||&nbsp;&nbsp;</center></html>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("sql error:" + ex);
            }
            DefaultTableModel df = new DefaultTableModel();
            df.setDataVector(dataValues, columnNames);
            JTable table = new JTable();
            table.setModel(df);
            int index = 0;
            while (index < 32) {
                TableColumn a = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
                a.setPreferredWidth(100);
                a.setResizable(false);
                index++;
            }
            JInternalFrame jif = new JInternalFrame();
            dtp.add(jif);
            jif.setResizable(true);
            jif.setLocation(new Point(ii * 30, ii * 20));
            jif.setSize(600, 150);
            jif.setVisible(true);
            JButton b = new JButton("Click me!");
            b.addActionListener(listener);
            jif.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            jif.add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
        gui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 600));
        gui.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Demo");
        f.add(gui);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TableWithHtml tableWithHtml = new TableWithHtml();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 You are really a swing master with `5K` reputation. Myself, I still did not get the Swing silver badge, one more up-vote to go ;)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad [this week one (better) man beat me](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/topusers) in the charts, because I'm leaving (july/2012) answering the questions for another posters here, stays here only as editor an voter